# Using schema to make a vue-form-generator section collapse-able

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using the [vue-form-generator](https://github.com/vue-generators/vue-form-generator/tree/master/src) library to create a form.

The problem is my form has 116 questions on it and I would like to collapse some questions, making the form more manageable for users.

My form has five sections. So each question in my form has the `section` attribute in the schema. However, the `section` part is not a form field such as `label` that you can modify. The sections are automatically generated into headings for you.

Apart from creating custom form fields, is there any way to make these sections collapse-able?

One route that I was thinking of trying would be to split my form into five forms, which will allow me to place a vue-bootstrap collapse element around each form. Something like:

```
<b-collapse id="collapse1" class="mt-2">
<vue-form-generator  :schema="survey.schema" :options="survey.formOptions" :model="survey.model"></vue-form-generator>
</b-collapse>
```

But this would then again make submission of the form more difficult, since I would have to splice the results of all five forms.

Is there any easier solution to this problem?

Comment: I tried using b-collapse-accordion from Bootstrap Vue and generate a new vue-form-generator for each section, but it didn't work. Did you find another solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently and this is the only way I found to solve it.

In the schema object add a `.collapse` class to the group like so:

```
const schema = {
  groups: [
    {
      styleClasses: 'collapse',
      legend: 'Group title',
      fields: [ ...
```

On the parent component add a `collapse` method and attach an `onclick` event to the `fieldset`'s `legend`, you can access the form in the vue `mounted` lifecycle hook, like below:

```
    ...
    methods: {
        collapse(e) {
            const group = e.target.parentElement;
            group.classList.toggle("hide");
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        const collapsableLegends = this.$el.querySelectorAll('.vue-form-generator .collapse legend');
        collapsableLegends.forEach(legend => legend.onclick = this.collapse);
    }
    ...
```

Finally add a `.hide` class to your css:

```
.vue-form-generator .collapse.hide .form-group { display: none }
```

It's a bit hacky, but it get the job done.